# MVVM viewmodel and model questions

Tags: mvvm

I'm trying to learn MVVM, and i'm struggling a little on differentiating between a model and viewmodel.

If someone could answer these 2 questions it would help clear a lot up for me:

Say I have an `Objects` class, which is a viewmodel that contains multiple ObservableCollections of `Object`.
The `Object` class contains an ObservableCollection of strings that are displayed on the GUI.

Is the `Object` class a model or viewmodel?

What if the `Object` class contains just a string and a integer (name and value), is it a model or viewmodel?

Comment: It is worth remembering that you can have just a model and a view, you do not have to have a view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Model` is the class that holds your *data*. The data can be strings /integers or whatever.
The `Model` can also be a *list / collection* of those objects. For example a List of `Person` objects can still be your `Model`.

The `ViewModel` is the tier *between* your Model and the View. It should be used to perform whatever tasks you need on the data (for instance, if your Model is a list of `Person` objects but you only want to show in your view people that are aged older then 18, this logic is done in the `ViewModel`)

So to answer your question:

If you have an object which contains the *data* (in your example a list of strings) it is the `Model`.
Even if the object is a little more complex (with relation to the number of properties it holds) it's probably still the Model.
Business Logic should be kept separate from the model. On the other hand [Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98681/Validating-User-Input-WPF-MVVM) *can* be added to the Model (for instance to make sure the `Age` property of a person is non-negative) since this is still rules on how your *data* should behave